# Appium driver OS name

Tags: ruby, appium

While writing script for Android and iOS in single file. How to check appium driver is created for iOS or Android? I have tried to check for version release but it gives build version only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check as below. 
This line of code will return true if you are using android driver otherwise false.

```
$driver.device_is_android?
```

Above line of code will work only after initializing driver.